# How to make a batch file wait for an Excel Macro to complete

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, batch-file, imacros

I've searched high and low for a solution but haven't been able to find one.

I have a batch file in which I call a JavaScript file which calls an Excel macro to run. I want the batch file to wait for the macro to complete, and then continue.

I use the JavaScript file to call the Excel macro because I don't know of a way to run the macro directly from the batch file. There's probably a better way, but I haven't been able to find one.

In my .bat file I've tried:

```
Do some batch stuff, including iMacros
WAIT/ cscript.exe RunExcelJScript.js
Do some more batch stuff with iMacros
```

but it doesn't wait for the macro to finish before continuing to Do some more batch stuff. I assume that it's because the .bat file is literally only waiting for the .js file to complete, not the Excel macro subsequently opened by the .js file.

I know I could use a timeout to set a certain period of waiting time, but the macro is quite complex and takes a long and varying time to run.

I need a way to EITHER:

- call the Excel macro to run directly from the .bat file so I can use /WAIT
- tell the JavaScript file to wait until the macro completes and then create a flag of some sort that will trigger the .bat file to continue.

The .bat/.js/Macro will run every 15 minutes.

My .js file is this:

```
var objXL = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
objXL.Visible = true;
objXL.WorkBooks.Open("FilePathTo/Enrollments.xlsm");
objXL.Run("NameOfExcelModule.UpdateAndExportToMoodle");
```

Can anyone offer a suggestion for how I can make the .bat file wait for my Excel macro to complete?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, just find the name of the imacro task. when the task is running %ERRORLEVEL% will be "0" when the task is finished %ERRORLEVEL% will change to "1" and the loop will end.

```
 :loop
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('tasklist ^| find "TaskName.exe"' ) do (
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
        ping -n 10 localhost > nul 2>nul
        goto loop
    )
)
```

Comment: I got the batch to wait for my Excel macro to run using the /WAIT method. Now I need it to wait for an iMacro that runs in Firefox. Your suggestion sounds promising and I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this by searching, the code I used to make the batch file wait for the Excel macro to run is "START "RunExcelScript" /WAIT cscript.exe RunExcelJScript.js". The .js file contents are shown in my original question.

Comment: Not for my original question, but I did use your idea (but slightly modified) to make the file wait for the iMacro. +1 for the idea. Thanks!